# Public Directory accessible by "Public" and "public"?

Tags: macos

I found something really weird with my `Public` directory on my Mac. I'm keeping some static files in there, they all work as expected. The weird thing is, I'm accessing the static files through a directory using `public` with a lowercase "p" not `Public`, and it still works.

I can't see any symbolic links between the two, nor does `public` exist on it's own as a duplicate directory. What else could be going on?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; general software questions are off topic. Also, if this is occurring on a Mac, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HFS+ filesystem on OS X is [case insensitive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-bash-in-osx-case-insensitive).